# Process NFT metadata on hedera chain

Tags: blockchain, metadata, ipfs, nft, hedera-hashgraph

I'm trying to get the metadata from the NFT on hedera chain.
When creating NFT the CID was converted to unit8array format but when I fetch the data the output is different.

I'm unable to retrieve the original CID value which was in metadata.

**link to the output of NFT data:** https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/accounts/0.0.48797750/nfts

When I check in Hackpack wallet the NFT images are there which are part of metadata, so the data is not lost. I'm just not able to process/get the metadata in proper format.

I tried to convert the input in formats [unit8array] and unit8array but both of them are giving some encoded value.

The output in metadata is neither hex of bin.

I need to convert it to CID so I can display NFT image to the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue recently for one of my projects, after some trial and error I discovered that the value in the meta data field being returned by the API request was actually in base 64, so all I had to do was decode it using Node Js Buffer.from method. I explained the process with an example in a thread. Follow the link below to check it out.
[devmaesters](https://www.devmaesters.com/blog/thread/25)